# Cannot set focus to the TextField inside ExpansionTile programmaticaly

Tags: flutter

I have an `ExpansionTile` with a `TextField` inside and trying to set the focus to this text field when user expands the tile. But for some reasons I can't get it working.
Here is the code:

```
ExpansionTile(
  key: PageStorageKey<String>("notes_key"),
  title: Text(
    "Notes",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo),
  ),
  onExpansionChanged: (expanded){
    if(expanded){
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_notesFocusNode);
      _notesController.value = _notesController.value.copyWith(text: _notes);
    } else {
      _notesFocusNode.unfocus();
    }
  },
  children: <Widget>[
   Row(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
         child: TextField(
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             border: InputBorder.none,
           ),
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
           keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
           focusNode: _notesFocusNode,
           controller: _notesController,
           key: PageStorageKey("notes_field_key"),
           minLines: 1,
           maxLines: null,
           onChanged: (value) => _notes = value,
         ),
       ),
       IconButton(
         icon: Icon(Icons.done),
         color: Colors.teal,
         onPressed: () => _notesFocusNode.unfocus(),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 ],
)
```

Any help appreciated.

For a bigger context, the text field is not inside any form. The provided piece of code lays inside the bigger one, where it is wrapped in the `ListView`. Probably I need to have some parent focus scope in my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextFormField` is not yet available to get `Focus` when you expand the `Tile`. It only becomes available after a few milliseconds of the animation starting. Since you don't have a way to know when the animation has finished, you can make a workaround by adding a delay. I would advise a minimum of `200` milliseconds so that the animation doesn't stagger but the `TextFormField` gets focus:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (){
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_notesFocusNode);
});
```

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you, but actually your idea is correct.
But such implementation of the `onExpansionChanged` property in the `ExpansionTile` in Flutter is pretty much useless for developer... Thanks for help.